# SSLStrip and WWWW Issue

Tags: ssl

I have been playing around with the mana-toolkit (https://github.com/sensepost/mana) which uses a revised form of SSLstrip to support HSTS.

I have noticed that SSLStrip adds an extra "w" to the domain url of pages that are under HTTPS. However on some devices, OS and web browsers the target web page does not appear and a blank page is shown, or the page is shown but not formatting or pictures (like the urls to css, js etc.. don't work) or an error is provided about too many re-directs.

Does anyone know what the issue is? Is it related to certain web browsers? Can it be mitigated somehow? It seems that this is a major flaw and kinda renders the solution haphazard in its success.

Regards

Comment: This does not appear to be a question relevant to security.

Comment: Hi - sorry I thought it is. SSLStrip is used for pentesting which is a component of IT security.

Comment: I checked the guidelines, and didn't realize tools questions were on topic.  My bad.

Comment: The problem is that this is tool-specific and technical - it's even a web server behaviour question. This is more of a support question than an InfoSec question.

Comment: Good points - though its not really web server - its end device issue. The tool is focussed within the security domain hence submitting it to this site. I will try general networking site as I see your point. I was hoping someone here who uses the tool in pentesting knows a fix or can comment on this behaviour.